# [WARNING]: module snow_record not found in: /usr/share/my_modules:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules

Tags: ansible

while i am using snow_record in playbook, i get below error.  Please help.

```
ERROR! no action detected in task. This often indicates a misspelled module name, or incorrect module path.
```

```
tasks:
- name: calling variable which has user/pass
  include_vars: /ansible/pass.yml

- name: read from snow
  snow_record_find:
     username: "{{ snow_username }}"
     password: "{{ snow_password }}"
     instance: mycompany
     state: present
     table: incident
     query:
       assignment_group: unix-support
     return_fields:
        - number
  register: host_list
```

```
# ansible-doc snow_record

[WARNING]: module snow_record not found in: /usr/share/my_modules:/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules

ansible 2.4.2.0
  config file = /home/m0156751/ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = [u'/usr/share/my_modules']
  ansible python module location - /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible
  executable location - /usr/bin/ansible
  python version = 2.7.5 (default, Aug 13 2020, 02:51:10) [GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an old version of ansible (2.4.2) where the service now modules do not exists (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/list_of_all_modules.html).

You need to upgrade to 2.5 to get the `snow_record` module.

But for the `snow_record_find` you need to upgrade to 2.9.

Starting from then, the module is part of the servicenow collection: https://galaxy.ansible.com/servicenow/servicenow

Besides having the right version of ansible to have the module, this specific module has some requirements (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/snow_record_find_module.html#requirements): you need to install python `pysnow` module on the host targeted by the module execution.
You can do that through `pip` or `package` (if pysnow is provided as a system package) modules in a task preceding the use of service now modules.

Comment: Now that i have upgraded ansible to 2.9. This time it is pysnow error.                                            ImportError: No module named pysnow. Failed to import the required Python library (pysnow) on

Comment: I was wondering about adding this info: some modules have requirements (documented in the module doc) and in that case it's `pysnow`